# Why does changing a parents data on NgOninit not cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError?

Tags: angular

Under this example

```
parentComponent {
  text = 'dsfsdf';
}

childComponent implements Oninit {
    @Input() text;
   ngOnInit() {
     this.text = 'something else';
    }
}
```

why does this not cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError please? And what is a simple way of getting this error to occur?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't trigger an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` because changing the value of an `@Input` parameter does not trigger any event to the parent and so it just doesn't re-render at all.

A simple way to make this error occur:

```
<div>{{functionThatReturnsDifferentValueOnEveryCall()}}</div>

...

count = 0;

functionThatReturnsDifferentValueOnEveryCall() {
   return count++;
}
```